# Get date of user sign up

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to be able to display how long the user has been signed up in their account dashboard.

```
<?php
  $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  $signUpDate = $customer['created_at'];
  $signUpYear = date('Y', strtotime($signUpDate));
?>
```

This works but it feels kind of hacky... Is there a more idiomatic way to find the year a user signed up in?

I'm working in `theme_name/default/template/customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  class `Mage_Core_Model_Date`'s function `date($format, $data)`  you can do same thing

```
Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y', $customer->getCreatedAt());
```

Use this ,Hope it will work for you